# Jenkins projects all showing up as the same

Tags: jenkins

I've been trying to set up different Jenkins projects, always choosing the "freestyle" option.  For some reason they always seem connected though (see image)

[image: Jenkins]

These projects were not built at the same time, and they are not both on build 54.  Even when setting them up even though they have different git addresses, they would both show the exact same workspace.  I manually entered custom workspaces to get them separate, and then it feels like I had to try creating the project several more times to finally get them showing separate workspaces.

Issue still remains that the stats now display them like they're the same project.

What do I have to do get these completely seperate so each project displays it's own stats instead of the 'last built' stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the builds and workspaces directories set incorrectly, and all projects were being build/read from the same directory.

The key was to add ${ITEM_FULL_NAME}, somewhere in the path to make them each have their own directories.

I had missed the setting as it's hidden in 'Manage Jenkins -> Advanced'

[image]

Comment: I don't remember ever having to set that up; it was always like that out of the box for me by default. I suppose you got yourself in trouble by editing it, eh?

Comment: I don't remember setting it up like that or editing that, but the jenkins instance was set up quite awhile ago, so yeah I must have changed them somewhere along the line :(